# Creating class/handle only from another class

Tags: c++, c++11, friend

I need only my mesh class to be able to create these classes, and i would like to not make these classes nested, because of too long qualified name if so. How can i do it best?

```
struct Handle
{
    explicit Handle(int i) : _index(i) {}
    bool IsValid() { return _index != NO_HANDLE; }

protected:
    enum { NO_HANDLE = -1 };
    int _index;
};

// **************************************************************************************
struct HalfEdgeHandle : Handle
{
    HalfEdgeHandle(int i) : Handle(i) {}
    static HalfEdgeHandle GetInvalid() { return HalfEdgeHandle(NO_HANDLE); }
};

// **************************************************************************************
struct FaceHandle : Handle
{
    FaceHandle(int i) : Handle(i) {}
    static FaceHandle GetInvalid() { return FaceHandle(NO_HANDLE); }
};

// **************************************************************************************
struct VertexHandle : Handle
{
    VertexHandle(int i) : Handle(i) {}
    static VertexHandle GetInvalid() { return VertexHandle(NO_HANDLE); }
};
```

Only invalid handle should be accessible outside, for now i think it can be done by using static variables.

Comment: It very hard to guess what you are after. Could you reword it... carefully? You don't have any nested classes. and what do you mean by "make a class"? I think you are misusing this term and you mean creating instances, I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use friend.

```
class Factory;

struct Handle
{
protected:
    explicit Handle(int i) : _index(i) {}
public:
    bool IsValid() { return _index != NO_HANDLE; }

protected:
    enum { NO_HANDLE = -1 };
    int _index;
    friend class Factory; // and so on in Derived classes
};
```

Comment: You mean, i need add friendship for all 4 classes? And put all constructors in protected or private areas?

Comment: @Yola yes, I mean this. Constuctor of derived classes should be in private section, if they have no childs.